# Replacing key values in object with array for loop javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I'm trying to change the values in the "notes" key to the values in the scale variable array. So after running the function the numbers in "notes" are now the corresponding letters from var scale. ex: the first "notes" key values in var chordArrays would read [d,f,a] instead of [1,3,5] and so forth.

```
  var chordArrays = [    
    {
    "chord type": "minor",
    "inversion": "root",
    "chords": [
      {
         "scale degree": "II",
         "notes": [1,3,5]
      },
      {
        "scale degree": "III",
        "notes": [2,4,6]
      },
      {
        "scale degree": "VI",
        "notes": [5,0,2]
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "chord type": "minor",
    "inversion": "first",
    "chords": [
      {
        "scale degree": "II",
        "notes": [3,5,1]
      },
      {
        "scale degree": "III",
        "notes": [4,6,2]
      },
      {
        "scale degree": "VI",
        "notes": [0,2,5]
      },
    ]
  }]

 var scale = [c,d,e,f,g,a,b]



function getMainChordsOfKey(scale,chordArrays) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chordArrays.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < chordArrays[i].chords.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < chordArrays[i].chords[j].notes.length; k++) {
        for (var z = 0; z < scale.length; z++) {
          if (chordArrays[i].chords[j].notes[k] === z) {
              replace k with z
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `chordArrays[i].chords[j].notes[k] = scale[z];`

Comment: Or, in just one line: `chordArrays.forEach(array => array.chords.forEach(chord => chord.notes = chord.notes.map(i => scale[i])));`

Comment: thanks for the much more efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

Your letters should be delimited with quotes, otherwise JS does not see them as strings, but as variable names.

Here is how you could do it:

```js
const chordArrays = [{ "chord type": "minor", "inversion": "root", "chords": [ { "scale degree": "II", "notes": [1,3,5] }, { "scale degree": "III", "notes": [2,4,6] }, { "scale degree": "VI", "notes": [5,0,2] }, ] }, { "chord type": "minor", "inversion": "first", "chords": [ { "scale degree": "II", "notes": [3,5,1] }, { "scale degree": "III", "notes": [4,6,2] }, { "scale degree": "VI", "notes": [0,2,5] }, ] }]

const scale = "cdefgab"; // Can be array or string. But use quotes.
 
for (const type of chordArrays) {
    for (const chord of type.chords) {
        chord.notes = chord.notes.map(note => scale[note]);
    }
}
 
console.log(chordArrays);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're looking for

```js
var chordArrays = [
  {
    'chord type': 'minor',
    inversion: 'root',
    chords: [
      {
        'scale degree': 'II',
        notes: [1, 3, 5]
      },
      {
        'scale degree': 'III',
        notes: [2, 4, 6]
      },
      {
        'scale degree': 'VI',
        notes: [5, 0, 2]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'chord type': 'minor',
    inversion: 'first',
    chords: [
      {
        'scale degree': 'II',
        notes: [3, 5, 1]
      },
      {
        'scale degree': 'III',
        notes: [4, 6, 2]
      },
      {
        'scale degree': 'VI',
        notes: [0, 2, 5]
      }
    ]
  }
];

var scale = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'b'];

chordArrays.forEach(o => {
  o.chords.forEach(n => {
    n.notes = n.notes.map(i => (i = scale[i]));
  });
});

console.log(chordArrays);

// sample on the DOM
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = chordArrays[0].chords[0].notes;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

[here's a link to a gist](https://gist.github.com/thall1961/83165b8e0a55bd5b298d2fb2043971b0)

Answer (score 0):

This is an immutable solution (does not change the original object)

```
chordArrays.map(chord => ({
  ...chord,
  chords: chord.chords.map(note => ({
    ...note,
    notes: note.notes.map(note => scale[note])
  }))
}))
```

-->

```
[{
"chord type": "minor",
"inversion": "root",
"chords": [
  {
    "scale degree": "II",
    "notes": [
      "d",
      "f",
      "a"
    ]
  }, ...]
```